# Samsung NP940X5N doesn't boot

Tags: boot, laptop, samsung, rfkill

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 at another partition than where a previous Ubuntu 18.04 has installed.
But failed to boot, and systemd seems are waiting for the swap partition to be mount. So I just comment the swap line out from fstab file.
But it still hangs, so I chrooted into it and run

> systemctl mask dev-nvme0n1p8.device

And reboot.(nvme0n1p8 is the swap)
It still hangs on systemd-rfkill.sevice and journal shows it always timeout.
But after I deleted the swap partition, it can boot now without any problem.

Btw, the 18.04 is always usable.
[Screenshot when booting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq1Ve.jpg)

Update on 20th May:

My laptop is Samsung Notebook 9 pro NP940X5N with i5-8250U.
After I deleted the swap partition, this bug still exists. And I found another post about it:
[Mostly unable to boot when [ ***] A start job is running for... FOREVER!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241036/mostly-unable-to-boot-when-a-start-job-is-running-for-forever)
It seems that there is still a rare probability to boot normally, and it exactly happened after I deleted the swap partition. 
And I tried more time later. if I turned off my laptop for a long time, on the next boot, it may more probably boot. but it mostly just doesn't work.